# How do I make such a table in LaTeX?

Tags: tables

Probably a very simple and maybe stupid question, but I haven't yet been able to figure out how to make a table like this in LaTeX:

[image]

So basically all that I want is the horizontal and vertical line that I drew to be boldfaced and then the rest of the columns and rows not to be separated by any lines. How could I do this in the easiest way? Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a very basic LaTeX table formatting task. Show your previous efforts by providing some code of your own. Or start reading a LaTeX tutorial or Lamports LaTeX manual about creating tables using the `tabular` environment.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I uploaded the image for you.

Comment: @AlexG I am quite familiar already with Latex, only not with making tables using Latex. I have tried searching how to make tables in the way I want using that environment but the ones I came across so far are not what I want. Maybe you could just try to help me instead of directly becoming offensive.

Comment: See http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Tables#Basic_examples , the first result of a google search for 'tables latex tutorial'

Comment: @AlexG And all of them are not the same as the one I want... But anyway, luckily there are also people who are willing to help.

Comment: Steven's [answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/120377) is a straightforward combination of the 2nd and 3rd examples within the 'Basic Examples' section of the Wiki page given above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I have a series of possible answers.  Choose the one you like (some of them use the package `booktabs`, as you can see in the code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}


\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\toprule
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\midrule
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\toprule
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\hline
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}


\begin{table}
\centering
\caption{Your caption here}\label{tab:yourlabel}
\begin{tabular}{l|lll}
\textbf{Hola1} & \textbf{Hola2} & \textbf{Hola3}\\
\hline
datum1 & datum2 &datum3 &etc\\
datum4 & datum5 &datum6 &etc\\
%\midrule
datum7 & datum8 &datum9 &etc\\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

They produce this:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much for your help :). That was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: My bad, I'll take notice of it in my future posts.

Comment: @Mario S. E.: this is part of a larger debate that is on the meta, but I think that it is OK to say thank you as a comment in an answer. A lot of times, when my solution is not accepted, I am left wondering whether the OP found my solution useful or not as I cannot know if the OP upvoted my answer or not.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c|ccc}
A & B & C & D\\
\hline
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4\\
1 & 2 & 3 & 4
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help :). This is simple but exactly what I need. Thanks a lot.